# Cloud Function Deployment - TypeError: instance.INTERNAL.registerComponent is not a function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this error when I try to deploy Cloud Functions. Have tried with `firebase-admin` 8.8.0, 8.7.0, and 8.6.1 (the last 3 versions)

Running `firebase-functions` 3.3.0

Any idea what the problem is? Anyone else have this issue?

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: instance.INTERNAL.registerComponent is not a function
    at registerDatabase (/PATH/cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15165:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/PATH/cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15196:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at FirebaseNamespace.get [as database] (/PATH/cloud-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:282:38)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include enough information that anyone can reproduce the problem, including code and configuration.  This is called an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Im getting the same error and to replicate the error I have narrowed it down to every time I am trying to access my admin.database()... For Example admin.database().ref('blah') throws this error

Answer (score 11):

```
instance.INTERNAL.registerComponent
```

resides inside firebase/app library

So running `npm install @firebase/app --save` fixes the issue

Comment: after a bunch of failed attempts, this fixed it for me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I already had @firebase/app as part of firebase. I also have node 12 installed with Win 10

```
npm ls @firebase/app
functions@ C:\Users\me\source\repos\admin\functions
`-- firebase@5.2.4
  `-- @firebase/app@0.6.13
```

I fixed the issue by updating the firebase dependencies to the latest.

```
npm i --save firebase@latest firebase-admin@latest firebase-functions@latest
```

From my package.json:

```
    "firebase": "^8.2.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
```

Note:
Always update firebase-tool to the latest:

```
   npm i -g firebase-tools@lates
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer, was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Solved on Github. Was a bug in Firebase

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/714

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/717